# Regex to match 3 completly different styles of text

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need 1 regex to re.compile on the following text:

```
2. Name Bla B'd
32. da Bla 'B'
4 Name Bla 'B'
232 data' Name Name
test Name Name
```

Should output:

```
Name Bla B'd
da Bla 'B'
Name Bla 'B'
data' Name Name
test Name Name
```

I've tried a bunch of them but I can't get it working at all :/
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I'm not the best with regex, I've tried these two about 5~ mins ago `(\d+.) (\s) (.+)` or `\d+. (.+)`

Comment: The closest I got was: `(\d+.|\d+|) (.+)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> s = """2. Name Bla B'd
... 32. da Bla 'B'
... 4 Name Bla 'B'
... 232 data' Name Name
... test Name Name"""
>>> result = re.sub(r"^[ \d.]+", "", s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
>>> print(result)
Name Bla B'd
da Bla 'B'
Name Bla 'B'
data' Name Name
test Name Name
```

**Explanation:**

- `[ \d.]+` matches a string that consists of spaces, digits and/or dots.
- The `^` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) makes sure that that string is only matched if it's at the beginning of a line.

Comment: It's not a multiline, I am originally using `re.compile` and then later `.match`

Comment: @Hyflex, well then you don't need the `MULTILINE` flag. But since you want to change the string, you'll still need to use `re.sub()`. `.match()` returns the matching part of the string, it doesn't remove it.

Comment: How come I am unable to use the regex in regex101 (my testing ground for regex's) but either way it works perfectly.